# Rails: how to correctly modify and save values of records in join table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, many-to-many, associations, rails-activerecord

I would like to understand why in Rails 4 (4.2.0) I see the following behaviour when manipulating data in a join table:

```
student.student_courses
```

returns all associated records of courses for a given user;

**but the following will save changes**

```
student.student_courses[0].status = "attending"
student.student_courses[0].save
```

**while this will not**

```
student.student_courses.find(1).status = "attending"
student.student_courses.find(1).save
```

Why is that, why are those two working differently, is the first one the correct way to do it ?

Comment: Are you expecting `Student.student_courses.find(1)` to reference the `status` variable? EDIT: fixed by edit.

Comment: yes, fixed it.. (but that was just a typo, it's not the source of the problem)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`student.student_courses[0]` and `student.student_courses.find(1)` are subtly different things.

When you say `student.student_courses`, you're just building a query in an `ActiveRecord::Relation`. Once you do something to that query that requires a trip to the database, the data is retrieved. In your case, that something is calling `[]` or `find`. When you call `[]`:

```
student.student_courses[0]
```

your `student` will execute the underlying query and stash all the `student_courses` somewhere. You can see this by looking at:

```
> student.student_courses[0].object_id
# and again...
> student.student_courses[0].object_id
# same number is printed twice
```

But if you call `find`, only one object is retrieved and a new one is retrieved each time:

```
> student.student_courses.find(1).object_id
# and again...
> student.student_courses.find(1).object_id
# two different numbers are seen
```

That means that this:

```
student.student_courses[0].status = "attending"
student.student_courses[0].save
```

is the same as saying:

```
c = student.student_courses[0]
c.status = "attending"
c.save
```

whereas this:

```
student.student_courses.find(1).status = "attending"
student.student_courses.find(1).save
```

is like this:

```
c1 = student.student_courses.find(1)
c1.status = "attending"
c2 = student.student_courses.find(1)
c2.save
```

When you use the `find` version, you're calling `status=` and `save` on entirely different objects and since nothing was actually changed in the one that you `save`, the `save` doesn't do anything useful.

Comment: So basically, it all depends on whether or not I am issueing a new query to the db or not, right? But how do I know what will trigger a DB request and what will not? In your answer you say that `stud.student_courses[0]` will execute the query and stash it somewhere, that's ok because I am understanding that it all got saved into `stud` when I did `stud = Student.find(10)`, so that every `stud.student_courses[N]` now requires no additional queries. But again how do I know which methods will still perform a new DB query again? What's the rationale behind it? Could you point me to some doc? Thx!

Comment: Also, a little side question... what happens if DB data is changed after initial my query? Will `student.student_courses[1]` still hold to my "old" data or will it reflect the changes "live" as they happen? What's the common way of dealing with this situation in Rails? I've seen around the use of #reload but still I'm questioning myself about the consequences of yet another very quick change in DB happening right after my #reload ...

Comment: I find most Rails documentation to be pretty much useless, sorry. Calling `find` always hits the database. Doing something to the association as a whole hits the database and stashes the result so array-ish things will use the same array. There is no locking unless you do it yourself so you won't know about changes that happen behind your back, the underlying assumption is that that won't happen.

Answer (score -1):

`student_courses` is an `ActiveRecord::Relation`, basically a `key => value` store. The `find` method would only work on a `model`

Comment: It looks like `find` is included in `ActiveRecord::Relation` via the `FinderMethods` module: http://www.rubydoc.info/docs/rails/3.0.0/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods#find-instance_method

Comment: but it does *find* and return the record like the array method does. Only thing, it's not able to save the data when doing `find(1).save` 
I'm still very puzzled.. could you point me somewhere in order to understand this on a broader level ? Thanks